# How to create decorator to validate image URL in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have to validate an image by its URI or its type. If i use this regex pattern it validates only the link `(http(s?):)([/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)` ends with this types but in my case it should validate both like. It should accept URL or else file type.
**Eg:**
**1)** **https://thevarsity.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/ARTS-TIFF_REVIEW-COURTESY_PHOTOKINO_LORBER-IMAGE_BOOK_STILL-1080x720.jpg**
**2)** 
Should accept image types like PNG,JPG,JPEG,GIF.
**sdfdsadasdsadsfdsf.png**

And am looking of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check against multiple regex statements by separating them with `|` like `regex_one|regex_two`

```
To check for the end portion say the extension, you can use $ symbol
```

Hope the below mentioned regex works for you.

```
/(http(s?):)([\/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg$|gif$|png$)|([\/|.|\w|\s|-])*\.(?:jpg$|gif$|png$)/
```

Comment: How to handle this type of url `https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=findSomeImage`

Comment: This pattern allows `http://www.example.com/asdf.pngs`. How to restrict this?